# Bordes inferiores no aparecen al abrir acordion en booststrap

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy realizando un page de registro con asp core haciendo uso de mvc, el formulario de usuarios implementa el uso de acordeones de Bootstrap pero el problema consiste al momento de abrir el borde inferior no se visualiza como se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación pongo el código que estoy implementado para saber que estoy realizando de manera errónea.

```
    @page "/Users/Registro"
@model RegisterModel
@{
    var image = "";
    if (Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Image != null)
    {
        image = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Image, 0
            , Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Image.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        image = "/images/user_icon.png";
    }

}*
<div class="container p-4">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header embed-responsive">
                        <output id="imageUser">
                            <img src=@image class="responsive imageUser" />
                        </output>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary" for="files">Cargar foto</label>
                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.AvatarImage" accept="image/*" type="file" id="files">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        @if (Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Id.Equals(0))
                        {
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Registro de Usuarios</h3>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Actualización de Usuarios</h3>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                            <div class="card rounded">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                                    <div id="header" class="bg-info rounded text-center">
                                        <h2 class="mb-0 t">
                                            @if (Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Id.Equals(0))
                                            {
                                                <button class="btn btn-link text-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                        data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                    Ingreso de Información
                                                </button>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <button class="btn btn-link text-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                        data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                    Actualización de Información
                                                </button>
                                            }

                                        </h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                                     data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.NID" type="number" placeholder="RUT" class="form-control" autofocus />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.NID" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Name" placeholder="NOMBRE" class="form-control"
                                                   Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.LastName" placeholder="APELLIDO" class="form-control"
                                                   Style="text-transform: uppercase" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.PhoneNumber" type="number" placeholder="CELULAR" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input asp-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Password" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA" class="form-control" />
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @if (!Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Id.Equals(0))
                                            {
                                                @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_USUARIO.Role", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_USUARIO.roles_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                             new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_USUARIO.Role", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_USUARIO.roles_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
     "ESCOGA UN ROL", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                            }
                                            <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_USUARIO.Role" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @if (Model.MODEL_USUARIO.Id.Equals(0))
                                            {
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Registro</button>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Actualizar</button>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="text-danger">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MODEL_USUARIO.ErrorMessage)  </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial">
}
```

Comment: Sospecho que el problema radica en los estilos de la página. Por favor adjunta el código css para que puedan ayudarte mejor.

Comment: no tiene codigo css adicional es solo bootstrap que viene en el asp core

Comment: Sí, tienes algunas clases que no son de Bootstrap, ejecutando tu código tal cual sin CSS adicional, funciona bien, no se corta como muestras en la imagen

Comment: Lo probaste y te visualizo sin problema?